# ubuntu ImportError: cannot import name MAXREPEAT

Tags: python, ubuntu

Upgrade to 13.04 has totally messed my system up .
I am having this issue when running

```
     ./manage.py runserver


Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./manage.py", line 8, in <module>
from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
File "/home/rats/rats/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management   
/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
from optparse import OptionParser, NO_DEFAULT
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/optparse.py", line 77, in <module>
import textwrap
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/textwrap.py", line 10, in <module>
import string, re
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/string.py", line 83, in <module>
import re as _re
File "/home/rats/rats/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 105, in <module>
import sre_compile
File "/home/rats/rats/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.py", line 14, in <module>
import sre_parse
File "/home/rats/rats/lib/python2.7/sre_parse.py", line 17, in <module>
from sre_constants import *
File "/home/rats/rats/lib/python2.7/sre_constants.py", line 18, in <module>
from _sre import MAXREPEAT
ImportError: cannot import name MAXREPEAT
```

this is happening for both the real environment as well as for virtual environment .
i tried removing python with

```
sudo apt-get remove python
```

and sadly it has removed everything .
now google chrome does not show any fonts .
i am looking for getting things back to work .
help is needed for proper configuring it again.

Comment: I guess this is an of mismatched python versions. Tell us which versions you have installed on your computer by using pyth <tab> <tab> at the terminal.

Comment: Seems like you have to reinstall your ubuntu to make it work.

Comment: @AlexanderAfanasiev Not necessary. I'm typing this from a computer whose Python I torched and revived.

Comment: @rats Has your GUI failed completely or is it just Chrome?

Comment: Yeah, agreed. Though who knows how much time will he waste on trying to revive it..

Comment: @AlexanderAfanasiev But probably reinstalling and investing time in learning virtualenv the next time around is the best strategy.

Comment: But if the situation's not too bad we can hopefully revive it :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python won't run due to ImportError: cannot import MAXREPEAT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15984650/python-wont-run-due-to-importerror-cannot-import-maxrepeat)

Comment: @WoLpH That has an answer for Windows based systems. This is a unix based system problem. (Not a duplicate).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you are using virtualenvwrapper then you can recreate the virtualenv on top of the existing one (with no environment currently active):

`mkvirtualenv <existing name>`

which should pull in the latest (upgraded) python version from the system and fix any mismatch errors.

Answer (score 30):

You don't need to recreate the environment.

You can upgrade the virtualenv running this command:

> virtualenv /PATH/TO/YOUR_OLD_ENV

`YOUR_OLD_ENV` folder will be properly upgraded to the version 2.7.4.

Comment: I have just tried that and it works great, it's a 5 seconds fix!

Comment: How can you find the path to your virtualenvs?

Comment: @babbaggeii Look in ~/.virtualenvs

Answer (score 8):

I have just solved that problem on my machine.

The problem was that Ubuntu 13.04 use python 2.7.4. That makes conflict with the Python version of the `virtualenv`.

What I do was to re-create the `virtualenv` with the new version of python. I think it's the simplest way, but you can try to upgrade the python version without re-creating all of the `virtualenv`.