# ImportError: No module named django.core.management

Tags: django

I tried "python manage.py runserver" and got the above error. Entering the python interpreter, I ran the command "from django.core.management import
execute_from_command_line" and got the following traceback:

```
>>> from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/andy/.virtualenvs/olp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from optparse import OptionParser, NO_DEFAULT
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/optparse.py", line 77, in <module>
    import textwrap
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/textwrap.py", line 10, in <module>
    import string, re
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/string.py", line 83, in <module>
    import re as _re
  File "/home/andy/.virtualenvs/olp/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 105, in <module>
    import sre_compile
  File "/home/andy/.virtualenvs/olp/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.py", line 14, in <module>
    import sre_parse
  File "/home/andy/.virtualenvs/olp/lib/python2.7/sre_parse.py", line 17, in <module>
    from sre_constants import *
  File "/home/andy/.virtualenvs/olp/lib/python2.7/sre_constants.py", line 18, in <module>
    from _sre import MAXREPEAT
ImportError: cannot import name MAXREPEAT
```

Does anyone know what's going on with this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16297892/ubuntu-importerror-cannot-import-name-maxrepeat can this be of any help?

Comment: Fantastic, thanks - that's sorted now.

Comment: @babbaggeii you can add and accept your own answer if you have fixed the issue