# setting up new virtualenv for Flask/Django using

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I am trying to setup a new virtual env to work with django and flask.

installed

```
sudo pip install virtualenv
sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

Then added in `.profile` these three lines;

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/Envs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/dev
source /Users/someone/anaconda/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

when i try to create a new project through

```
$ mkproject helloFlask
```

Error:

```
someone$ mkproject helloFlask
New python executable in helloFlask/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...
  Complete output from command /Users/someone/Envs/helloFlask/bin/python -c "import sys, pip; sys...d\"] + sys.argv[1:]))" setuptools pip:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/someone/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-6.0.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "/Users/someone/anaconda/lib/python2.7/optparse.py", line 77, in <module>
    import textwrap
  File "/Users/someone/anaconda/lib/python2.7/textwrap.py", line 10, in <module>
    import string, re
  File "/Users/someone/anaconda/lib/python2.7/string.py", line 83, in <module>
    import re as _re
  File "/Users/someone/Envs/helloFlask/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 105, in <module>
    import sre_compile
  File "/Users/someone/Envs/helloFlask/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.py", line 14, in <module>
    import sre_parse
  File "/Users/someone/Envs/helloFlask/lib/python2.7/sre_parse.py", line 17, in <module>
    from sre_constants import *
  File "/Users/someone/Envs/helloFlask/lib/python2.7/sre_constants.py", line 18, in <module>
    from _sre import MAXREPEAT
ImportError: cannot import name MAXREPEAT
```

What I am missing here ?

Comment: have you already checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16297892/ubuntu-importerror-cannot-import-name-maxrepeat ? By what I remember the issue is connected with the python version 2.7.4

Comment: @aberna in case you have any idea, should I save the file as conda-workon *sh https://gist.github.com/mangecoeur/5161488