# ImportError: cannot import name MAXREPEAT with cx_Freeze

Tags: python, python-2.7, cx-freeze

I'm running into an issue with `cx_Freeze` when running a frozen application (works fine unfrozen).

When running the program it results in the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cx_Freeze/initscripts/Console.py", line 27, in <module>
    exec code in m.__dict__
  File "PythonApp/mainframe.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dbus/__init__.py", line 103, in <module>
    from dbus._dbus import Bus, SystemBus, SessionBus, StarterBus
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dbus/_dbus.py", line 39, in <module>
    from dbus.bus import BusConnection
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 39, in <module>
    from dbus.connection import Connection
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 27, in <module>
    import threading
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 44, in <module>
    module='threading', message='sys.exc_clear')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/warnings.py", line 57, in filterwarnings
    import re
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 105, in <module>
    import sre_compile
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.py", line 14, in <module>
    import sre_parse
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/sre_parse.py", line 17, in <module>
    from sre_constants import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/sre_constants.py", line 18, in <module>
    from _sre import MAXREPEAT
ImportError: cannot import name MAXREPEAT
```

I'm on linux using a version of python 2.7.4 that I built from source, and importing `_sre` from a prompt works and I can access the `MAXREPEAT` constant.

This is usually down to `cx_Freeze` not pulling everything into `library.zip` and can be fixed by explicitly naming the module in `cx_Freeze`s setup include list and is the [solution to this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223128/cx-freeze-importerror-cannot-import-name), but that hasn't helped here.

This `_sre` module seems weird.. there's no `_sre` file in the `library.zip` generated but from that error it seems like it can find it, however it can't import that symbol? Surely if the module wasn't there it would be a "`No module named _sre`" error. Or possibly a circular import but `_sre` stub doesn't have any imports.

What's odd is I can't seem to find the file either - is this module dynamically created when importing somehow?

```
find /usr/local/lib/python2.7 -name "_sre*"
```

doesn't return anything, and the imported `_sre` module doesn't have a `__file__` attribute either, so I've no idea how to make sure it's included as it shows up as a built-in.

```
>>> import _sre
>>> _sre.__file__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__file__'
>>> repr(_sre)
"<module '_sre' (built-in)>"
```

This is [similar to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15984650/python-wont-run-due-to-importerror-cannot-import-maxrepeat) also which was asked recently, but in this case he was getting the error in the regular interpreter, however for me it's just in `cx_Freeze`.

### edit

Running `python -v` does seem like it's a built-in, so I'm not sure why `cx_Freeze` can miss it, or how I'd fix it.

```
...
# /usr/local/lib/python2.7/re.pyc matches /usr/local/lib/python2.7/re.py
import re # precompiled from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/re.pyc
# /usr/local/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.pyc matches /usr/local/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.py
import sre_compile # precompiled from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.pyc
import _sre # builtin
# /usr/local/lib/python2.7/sre_parse.pyc matches /usr/local/lib/python2.7/sre_parse.py
import sre_parse # precompiled from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/sre_parse.pyc
...
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`_sre` is a [built in module](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/sys#sys.builtin_module_names), so there's no file to include for it, but it doesn't have a MAXREPEAT attribute in Python 2.7.3:

```
>>> import _sre
>>> _sre
<module '_sre' (built-in)>
>>> _sre.MAXREPEAT
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'MAXREPEAT'
```

My best guess is that your frozen copy somehow has the standard library .py modules from Python 2.7.4, but the compiled Python interpreter from 2.7.3 or an earlier version. I see you're working from `/usr/local` - maybe it's picking up an older version from `/usr`.

Comment: How does `cx_Freeze` find the interpreter to use? by looking in `$PATH`? I'll try printing out the python version number on the first line and see.

Comment: You're spot on by the way :) `print sys.version` on the first line shows the interpreter in the frozen version is `2.7.3`. I guess the clue was that `_sre` is imported on interpreter start up in `2.7.4` but in my frozen application it was thrown later when I did `import dbus`.

Comment: Ok, I thought I'd clear out the version of `2.7.3` so it wouldn't pick it up.. but it appears I don't have a version of `2.7.3`! I have `2.7.4` in `/usr/local` and `2.6.6` in `/usr`. Any idea of how this could be happening?

Comment: Nothing springs to mind. You could try `locate libpython2.7` to look for other copies. Otherwise, try clearing out everything you can that's not essential for the system (i.e. don't remove the copy from /usr - most Linux systems use Python a lot), and then installing it afresh.

Comment: wiping python and re-installing did solve this, thanks. I think 2.7.3 was on there before and 2.7.4 must have installed over the top of it leaving some .3 bits lying about perhaps. Thank you for the clues!

Comment: I upgraded to 2.7.5 and I've got the same issue (Not the MAXREPEAT error) but frozen apps with cx_Freeze are running 2.7.4 some how, my interpreter is 2.7.5 outside - so I don't think it's a virtualenv issue. (I recreated it without virutalenv as well).

Comment: How did you upgrade? It must be finding the 2.7.4 Python shared library (.so file) somewhere.

Comment: @ThomasK Ah only seeing your reply now, I just did `python setup.py install` on the source I believe

Comment: I think I meant how did you upgrade Python. But I don't know that I'll be able to offer much more advice anyway.

Comment: @ThomasK I didn't get notified you had replied again :P sorry! That is how I upgraded python (`python setup.py install` on the 2.7.5 source)

Comment: @ThomasK, Where can i find that `_sre` file in python library.I have installed python(2.7) on my windows machine, And i found `sre.py` file in the `Lib` folder,But where is the `_sre` file in that..?

Comment: @Shiva: there's no file for `_sre`, it's one of the modules that are built into the Python interpreter.

Answer (score 32):

I encountered this problem when I just upgraded from ubuntu 12.10 to 13.04, and I fixed this by copying the /usr/bin/python to /path/to/my/env/bin/, and it worked just fine

`cp /user/bin/python   /path/to/my/env/bin/`

or, there's a more elegant way to fix this([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16297892/ubuntu-importerror-cannot-import-name-maxrepeat)):

`mkvirtualenv <existing virtualenv name>`

Comment: as suggested in the same referenced question, `virtualenv <existing virtualenv name>` allows you to update the virtualenv without using virtualenvwrapper.

Comment: mkvirtualenv is perfect, thanks. In case anyone is concerned about it destroying and other files in the virtualenv, it DOESN'T!!

Comment: Upgraded from ubuntu 12.10 to 13.04 and faced the same above issue. Ran virtualenv <existing virtualenv name> on the existing virtualenv and this solved the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If all else fails, I got things running using this: http://www.kiwisoft.co.uk/blog/2014/08/17/fixed-importerror-cannot-import-name-maxrepeat

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem recently. Setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH=
solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was using cx_freeze 4.3.2 on my win 8 machine and it was always showing `ImportError: cannot import name MAXREPEAT with cx Freeze` if I ever tried to freeze a non built-in module, and once I downloaded version 4.3.1, it works, I'm able to freeze my all python 3.3 programs without any problem now.

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar issues on windows 8 - was just a PYTHONPATH issue.  check that PYTHONPATH exists by typing the following into a python session:

> > > import os
> > >
> > > os.environ['PYTHONPATH'].split(os.pathsep)

if you get an error set your PYTHONPATH using this approach..

[How to add to the pythonpath in windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7)