# Upgrading a Python Project from version 2.7 to 2.7.4

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I have a Django "project" that I have inherited, which I am developing in Eclipse. On my OS (windows 7 32 bit), I have Python 2.7.4 installed, likewise for my virtualenv. However, on my project (extracted from SVN) the Python version is 2.7 only.

This causes a conflict when trying to create another superuser (I do not know the original superuser name/password) where I get the message:

> cannot import maxrepeat

How do I upgrade the python version located at:

`c:\users\"username"\workspace\"project"\scripts`

from 2.7 to 2.7.4?

Apologies if I have omitted some important details, or if I am asking the wrong question as I am newbie to Django/python development.

**EDIT**
Having spoken to a friend before referring back to these responses (thanks btw), he advised me to copy over the contents of the 'scripts' folder within my virtualenv to the folder:

`c:\users\"username"\workspace\"project"\scripts`

I did that, so in theory, they are both now running from python version 2.7.4.

However, when I run the script

`python manage.py createsuperuser`

I get the following FULL Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in 
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\users\alecc\workspace\hub\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py"
, line 453, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\users\alecc\workspace\hub\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py"
, line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\users\alecc\workspace\hub\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py"
, line 263, in fetch_command
    app_name = get_commands()[subcommand]
  File "C:\users\alecc\workspace\hub\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py"
, line 109, in get_commands
    apps = settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "C:\users\alecc\workspace\hub\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 53,
in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\users\alecc\workspace\hub\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 48,
in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\users\alecc\workspace\hub\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 134,
 in __init__
    raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SE
TTINGS_MODULE, e))
ImportError: Could not import settings 'hub.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module name
d hub.settings
```

I have checked the system variables and I'm sure my project is on the Python system path. I have also checked  `'django.contrib.auth'` is enabled in my INSTALLED_APPS in the `settings.py`file.

**Edit 2**
Many other posts suggest it's a cross over of Python versions. However when I check the version number using the command:

`$scripts\python.exe --version`

I get Python 2.7.4 for each installation (Project & virtualenv)

Comment: Is it `MAXREPEAT` in capitals perhaps?

Comment: Is that the full error text, or did you get a traceback?

Comment: Perhaps related ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16301735/importerror-cannot-import-name-maxrepeat-with-cx-freeze

Comment: @MartijnPieters it was in capitals

Comment: @WayneWerner sorry I originally didn't put the full traceback. I realise that wasn't useful! I have done so in the edit

Comment: @karthikr I have looked through that post, and I'm afraid I cannot make full sense of the resolution. I am not sure it now applies as the error has changed (see edit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this information:

```
File "C:\users\alecc\workspace\hub\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 134,
 in __init__
    raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SE
TTINGS_MODULE, e))
ImportError: Could not import settings 'hub.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module name
d hub.settings
```

It looks like your application is called `hub`? The problem here is that it's *trying* to import `hub.settings` - but it can't find it. So for some reason, your `settings.py` is not on the path.

You can check this by editing `C:\users\alecc\workspace\hub\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py`, and somewhere before line 134 you can put `import sys; print(sys.path)`. Then check to see that the path where your `settings.py` file lives is available. If it is, something else weird is happening.

If not, just go ahead and pull those lines from the `__init__`, and try running `manage` from the same directory your settings file is in.

Comment: Thanks! I would give you an up vote if I had the necessary rep.

Comment: My app is called hub you're correct (I should have explained that). Trying to check where `settings.py` file was lead me to realise it was looking for a folder, within the application, called hub. Therfore, it was trying to find a file `hub/hub/__init__.py` and couldn't. Annoyingly, the error didn't indicate this. I also didn't realise it was a requirement to have this folder, named after the application itself, within the root destination, containing a `___init__.py` file. I just created it and.. voila!

Comment: It *did* actually indicate it, just in a slightly more esoteric way ;) It's a bit of a hard problem to know exactly what you were trying to do, so it gave the best answer it could give - somewhere it tried to `import hub.settings` (or maybe `__import__('hub.settings')`). Python really has no clue about Django, or what the intended project structure is supposed to look like - only about imports. Glad it helped!