# Installing scikit: ImportError: cannot import name MAXREPEAT

Tags: python, installation, ubuntu-12.04, scikit-learn

I'm running elementary OS (a derivative of Ubuntu 12.04) on which I have installed:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2013, 20:08:41) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
NumPy 1.8.0, SciPy 0.12.0, Matplotlib 1.2.1
```

I decided to install `scikit` following the simple instructions given [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html#install-by-distribution), which is basically the line:

```
sudo apt-get install python-sklearn
```

but it fails with the error:

```
...
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/sre_parse.py", line 17, in <module>
    from sre_constants import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/sre_constants.py", line 18, in <module>
    from _sre import MAXREPEAT
ImportError: cannot import name MAXREPEAT
```

Someone apparently had a similar issue here [ImportError: cannot import name MAXREPEAT with cx_Freeze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16301735/importerror-cannot-import-name-maxrepeat-with-cx-freeze) but I'm not sure the questions are equivalent and the answer given tells me very little about how to fix my install. Thoughts?

Comment: Seems like a problem in the Ubuntu package management.

Comment: You seem to have a second copy of Python 2.7 in `/usr/local`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever the issue was, running:

```
sudo pip install -U scikit-learn
```

installed it correctly.