# cx-freeze executable crashes on importing re

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

I have a small (< 300 lines) program that I'd like to bundle for release on Windows. Sadly, whenever I run the executable, it fails when it attempts to import anything. It crashes on the very first line, which is `import re, configparser as conf`.

```
c:\Python33\opencourses\dist>.\opencourses.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console3.py", line 2
7, in <module>
    exec(code, m.__dict__)
  File "opencourses.py", line 19, in <module>
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1567, in _find_a
nd_load
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1534, in _find_a
nd_load_unlocked
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 497, in set_pack
age_wrapper
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 510, in set_load
er_wrapper
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 608, in _require
s_frozen_wrapper
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 713, in load_mod
ule
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 313, in _call_wi
th_frames_removed
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\re.py", line 122, in <module>
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1567, in _find_a
nd_load
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1534, in _find_a
nd_load_unlocked
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 497, in set_pack
age_wrapper
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 510, in set_load
er_wrapper
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 608, in _require
s_frozen_wrapper
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 713, in load_mod
ule
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 313, in _call_wi
th_frames_removed
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\sre_compile.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1567, in _find_a
nd_load
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1534, in _find_a
nd_load_unlocked
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 497, in set_pack
age_wrapper
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 510, in set_load
er_wrapper
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 608, in _require
s_frozen_wrapper
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 713, in load_mod
ule
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 313, in _call_wi
th_frames_removed
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\sre_parse.py", line 17, in <module>
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1567, in _find_a
nd_load
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1534, in _find_a
nd_load_unlocked
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 497, in set_pack
age_wrapper
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 510, in set_load
er_wrapper
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 608, in _require
s_frozen_wrapper
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 713, in load_mod
ule
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 313, in _call_wi
th_frames_removed
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\sre_constants.py", line 18, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name MAXREPEAT
```

**Edit:** Actually, it's specifically the `re` module which is causing the issue. I tested that by changing which modules I import first -- `time` imports fine, but `urllib`, which somehow has a dependency on `re`, fails with a similar error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console3.py", line 2
7, in <module>
    exec(code, m.__dict__)
  File "opencourses.py", line 20, in <module>
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1616, in _handle
_fromlist
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 313, in _call_wi
th_frames_removed
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1567, in _find_a
nd_load
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1534, in _find_a
nd_load_unlocked
  File "C:\Python33\lib\urllib\request.py", line 84, in <module>
    import base64
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1567, in _find_a
nd_load
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1534, in _find_a
nd_load_unlocked
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 497, in set_pack
age_wrapper
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 510, in set_load
er_wrapper
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 608, in _require
s_frozen_wrapper
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 713, in load_mod
ule
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 313, in _call_wi
th_frames_removed
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\base64.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1567, in _find_a
nd_load
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1534, in _find_a
nd_load_unlocked
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 497, in set_pack
age_wrapper
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 510, in set_load
er_wrapper
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 608, in _require
s_frozen_wrapper
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 713, in load_mod
ule
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 313, in _call_wi
th_frames_removed
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\re.py", line 122, in <module>
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1567, in _find_a
nd_load
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1534, in _find_a
nd_load_unlocked
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 497, in set_pack
age_wrapper
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 510, in set_load
er_wrapper
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 608, in _require
s_frozen_wrapper
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 713, in load_mod
ule
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 313, in _call_wi
th_frames_removed
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\sre_compile.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1567, in _find_a
nd_load
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1534, in _find_a
nd_load_unlocked
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 497, in set_pack
age_wrapper
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 510, in set_load
er_wrapper
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 608, in _require
s_frozen_wrapper
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 713, in load_mod
ule
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 313, in _call_wi
th_frames_removed
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\sre_parse.py", line 17, in <module>
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1567, in _find_a
nd_load
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1534, in _find_a
nd_load_unlocked
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 497, in set_pack
age_wrapper
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 510, in set_load
er_wrapper
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 608, in _require
s_frozen_wrapper
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 713, in load_mod
ule
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 313, in _call_wi
th_frames_removed
  File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\sre_constants.py", line 18, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name MAXREPEAT
```

Sadly, this means I can't work around my own `re` dependence, since other modules depend on it as well :(

Answer (score 0):

I found [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16301735/importerror-cannot-import-name-maxrepeat-with-cx-freeze?rq=1) with the same problem, and fortunately the same solution. I updated my install from 3.3.0 to 3.3.3 and now it all works great.