# Python Cmd/Powershell error "Traceback (Most recent call last)"

Tags: python, powershell, python-2.7, cmd

I was giving a look at the "[Learn Python The Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex0.html#windows)" tutorial and when it told me to try it out by typing Python in Powershell after I installed it just kept giving me this:

```
PS C:\Users\Zach> python
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\lib\site.py", line 548, in <module>
main()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site.py", line 530, in main
known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site.py", line 266, in addusersitepackages
user_site = getusersitepackages()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site.py", line 241, in getusersitepackages
user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
File "C:\Python27\lib\site.py", line 231, in getuserbase
USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
File "C:\Python27\lib\sysconfig.py", line 516, in get_config_var
return get_config_vars().get(name)
File "C:\Python27\lib\sysconfig.py", line 449, in get_config_vars
import re
File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 105, in <module>
import sre_compile
File "C:\Python27\lib\sre_compile.py", line 14, in <module>
import sre_parse
File "C:\Python27\lib\sre_parse.py", line 17, in <module>
from sre_constants import *
File "C:\Python27\lib\sre_constants.py", line 18, in <module>
from _sre import MAXREPEAT
ImportError: cannot import name MAXREPEAT
```

I also tried running through the command prompt and got the same error. I've installed and uninstalled python about 3 times and have done a few reboots to no avail. I am very new to python and I'm confused on what to do here. I would also appreciate any links to other python tutorials.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15984650/python-wont-run-due-to-importerror-cannot-import-maxrepeat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, from my understanding, you have no modules called "MAXREPEAT" or you(or the installer) have installed it somewhere wrong. A reinstallation or redirecting the path should get it to work.

Comment: I tried making a new install into a new directory and it worked! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @user2852735 No problem! Glad I was able to help :)